# Find quoted text and color it green with javascript similar to 4chan greentext?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

For example text like:

```
>11 years old
>twin brother dies
>parents dont let me go to his funeral or tell me where it is
>tells me it would be innapropriate to be there as it could confuse people    
i dided
```

How do I match `>` in an element and turn it green? The functionality should be similar to 4chans "greentext" meaning that the "i dided" part up there should not turn green

Comment: @webbm I tried using `[>]\w+` for regex but it skips the space part meaning for code like `>11 years old`, only 11 is highlighted. I do not know how to make regex stop scanning at new line + I do not know how to make it detect whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it matches > at the start of the line and then anything after it (on the same line)

`>.*/g`

`/g` is used to match globally.

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/WXEoaW/2

Comment: hey @webbm, is there a way to make your solution not detect if there are words at the back? For example `random >11 years old` should not highlight because there is random at the back

Comment: You can use something like this: `(.*)?(>.*)`, where the first `(.*)?` is an optional `?` match on anything `(.*)` then the second is what we checked before. https://regex101.com/r/WXEoaW/3 I put the 2nd into a capturing group as it makes it easier to use that later for input/output

Comment: Ohh thanks for the knowledge! But what I meant is that I want the `>11 years` old to not highlight because there is a `random` at the back. Only those who do not have words at the back should highlight. Still I learned quite a lot in your example!

Comment: In that case you'll want to do this: `^>.*$/g` where `^` asserts position at the start of a line.

Comment: `^>.*$/g` does not work https://regex101.com/r/LYsL9Y/1. What you probably meant is `^>.*$/gm` https://regex101.com/r/LYsL9Y/2